# Convert a string ("MyExampleClass") into a class name (MyExampleClass)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-runtime

I want to convert a string to a class name. Imagine that I have a string, which changes, containing a class name, for example, the string `"MyExampleClass"`. Now, I want to create an object of the class `MyExampleClass`. I have to get the class name from the string. I want to do something like the following. (Consider the code just as a sketch.)

```
NSString *classNameStr = "MyExampleClass";
id theClass = [UIClass classFromString:classNameStr];
theClass *myObject = [[theClass alloc] init];
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: have you yet read the java tutorial about reflection?

Comment: @atk: Doesn't the iOS has different syntax?

Comment: Apologies.  I had thought I saw "java" in the tags.  I was mistaken :)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Here's what you'd want:

```
Class theClass = NSClassFromString(classNameStr);
id myObject = [[theClass alloc] init];
```

Note that you can't use `theClass` as a type name (i.e. `theClass *myObject`). You'll have to use `id` for that.

Answer (score 22):

You want `NSClassFromString`:

```
NSString *classNameStr = @"MyExampleClass";
Class theClass = NSClassFromString(classNameStr);
id myObject = [[theClass alloc] init];
```

You can also use the objc runtime interfaces (e.g. `objc_getClass(const char* name)`, `objc_lookUpClass(const char* name)`). The former will not load a class. The latter will. That option could be a good thing in some cases.

Answer (score 6):

```
id a = [[NSClassFromString(@"MyExampleClass") alloc] init];
```

use this one this will give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to build your classes dynamically, I recommend you to better take a look at the factory method design pattern, otherwise you will be loosing track of who builds what and how.

To do so, you can code a class that receives a string and returns a class depending on the input string.

Take a look at the book "Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software" by 
Erich Gamma; Richard Helm; Ralph Johnson; John Vlissides.