# How to abstract class names or types in Objective C to use as variables?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, abstract-class

I've realized that several of my list view controllers behave in the same way, and now I want to abstract them into a generic one called ListVC.  The plan is to create an instance of ListVC when its needed, and pass into it all of the specific things needed for that instance of it.

For example, if I need a list of customers I would do something like:

```
ListVC *customersVC = [[ListVC alloc] init];
customersVC.tableArray = self.customersList
```

In ListVC, there are times when I need to know certain object's class type.  In my example, the objects in the array `self.customersList` are from the class `CustomerClass`.  I know I can [convert strings to class names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654568/convert-a-string-myexampleclass-into-a-class-name-myexampleclass) but that doesn't help when I have a method inside ListVC that needs to return the object's type.  For example, in ListVC, this old non-abstracted method:

```
- (CustomerClass *)customerAfterFilter
```

should be something like:

```
- (self.objectClass *)objectAfterFilter
```

And I'd set objectClass after it was instantiated like so.

```
ListVC *customersVC = [[ListVC alloc] init];
customersVC.tableArray = self.customersList    
customersVC.objectClass = [CustomerClass class];
```

How do I do something like this?  Or if my approach is just wrong, please suggest the correct approach.  I'm a beginner in programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the return type like that. What you can do is return an `id`, which is a pointer to an object of any class.

```
- (id)objectAfterFilter
```

**EDIT:**

```
Customer *c = [customersVC objectsAfterFilter];
[c duCustomerStuff];
```

Alternatively:

```
[((Customer *)[customersVC objectsAfterFilter]) doCustomerStuff];
```

Comment: How would I then access the returned object's properties and methods?

Comment: Simply as you would normally. Changing the return type to `id` doesn't do anything to the object. You just lose some of the safety, because the compiler won't know the type either. You can however use a regular pointer to save the returned object's reference. See my edit.